# SonataUser - Extending Admin

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm trying to modify the default admin of the `User` entity.
Just need to remove certain fields from the form actually.

I imagine [this doc](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/advance.html#admin-extension) will be usefull for me when it'll be available.
For now I have created this admin and tried to override the default `User` one.

**app/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php**

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseType;

class UserAdmin extends BaseType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('username')
            ->add('groups')
            ->add('enabled')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('plainPassword', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            ->with('Groups')
                ->add('groups', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            ->with('Profile')
                ->add('firstname', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('lastname', null, array('required' => false))
            ->end()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function preUpdate($user)
    {
        $this->getUserManager()->updateCanonicalFields($user);
        $this->getUserManager()->updatePassword($user);
    }

    /**
     * @return UserManagerInterface
     */
    public function getUserManager()
    {
        return $this->userManager;
    }

}
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    sonata.admin.extension:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin.extension, target: sonata.user.admin.user }
        arguments: [null, Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User, SonataUserBundle:UserAdmin]
```

But I'm getting

> Cannot import resource "/var/www/Symfony/app/config/." from "/var/www/Symfony/app/config/routing.yml".
>   ...
>   ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin::addExtension() must be an instance of Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminExtensionInterface, instance of Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin given, called in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3139 and defined in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle/Admin/Admin.php line 2359

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

In case someone will look this up someday, I got this working by overriding UserAdmin.php

add following line into registerBundle method of app/AppKernel.php

```
// app/AppKernel.php
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // other bundle declarations
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle(),
    );
}
```

Now set value of sonata.user.admin.user.class parameter to the FQCN of the User entity which was created during FOSUserBundle setup.

```
//app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    #....
    sonata.user.admin.user.entity: YourVendor\YourBundle\Entity\User
```

Now create a class that extends default UserAdmin class and override configureShowFields, configureFormFields, configureDatagridFilters and configureListFields methods to add the needed user admin fields. Following is the sample extended UserAdmin class which is based on the bare bone user entity created in FOSUserBundle documentation.

```
<?php
//src/YourVendor/YourBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php

namespace YourVendor\YourBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;


class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('email')
            ->end()
            // .. more info
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {

        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('plainPassword', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            // .. more info
            ;

        if (!$this->getSubject()->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            $formMapper
                ->with('Management')
                    ->add('roles', 'sonata_security_roles', array(
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'required' => false
                    ))
                    ->add('locked', null, array('required' => false))
                    ->add('expired', null, array('required' => false))
                    ->add('enabled', null, array('required' => false))
                    ->add('credentialsExpired', null, array('required' => false))
                ->end()
            ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filterMapper)
    {
        $filterMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('locked')
            ->add('email')
        ;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('enabled', null, array('editable' => true))
            ->add('locked', null, array('editable' => true))
            ->add('createdAt')
        ;

        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')) {
            $listMapper
                ->add('impersonating', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataUserBundle:Admin:Field/impersonating.html.twig'))
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Now set the value of sonata.user.admin.user.class to the FQCN of the created UserAdmin class in app/config/config.yml, e.g

```
parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.user.class: YourVendor\YourBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
```

If everything setup correctly you will see an new users row in admin/dashboard page. All user operations should work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

In your config.yml, add the following:

```
parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.user.class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the tag in your service definition

```
tags:
    - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: some.menu, label: User }
```

Comment: This removes the error, but it's giving a new block in the dashboard named `default` with an entity named `-`. And `Add`/`List` links from `Users` and `-` are pointing to the standard `User` admin

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to set the label, and how to put this admin in a group

Comment: Actually I'd like to replace the current User admin, not adding a new one.

Comment: have u found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Same fix for Symfony 2.1, you need to specify custom UserAdmin class for Sonata bundle like this

```
sonata_user:
    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle
```

Also check Sonata UserBundle [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) for more options

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because you are trying to create admin extension and your class is not implementing AdminExtensionInterface. You could also extend the abstract AdminExtension class, which implements the interface.

This is clearly defined in the documentation of Sonata Admin Bundle - Extensions: 
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/extensions.html